# Incorrect x intercept in plot?

Tags: plotting

[image]

As you can see the x intercept is wrong it should be 71/7

Comment: Try `expr = (71 - 7*x)/10; Plot[expr, {x, -5, 20}]`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Mq8.png)  so Mathematica was right.  Which version did you use to make the plot? I am using V 13.1. You need to add `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` for your case to see it correctly.

Comment: Thank you thats work

Comment: The axes origin is not at `y == 0` and the range of `x` is not large enough to show the intercept. `Plot[(71 - 7 x)/10, {x, -5, 11}]`

Answer (score 6):

You need to set `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` to correctly see it. Here is an example

```
expr = (71 - 7*x)/10;
Plot[expr, {x, -5, 6}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But notice what happens now

```
expr = (71 - 7*x)/10;
Plot[expr, {x, -5, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So Mathematica is correct

```
Solve[expr == 0, x] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see it better, increase the domain, and now `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` is not needed.

```
expr = (71 - 7*x)/10;
Plot[expr, {x, -5, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica Plot has heuristics to decide the range to use for best view. This might not always be what you want. You can always force the origin to be where you want it using `AxesOrigin` option.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `PlotRange`:

```
Plot[(71 - 7*x)/10, {x, -5, 6}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 11}}]
```

[image]